# Bootstrap 3: How to make accordion panels as long as the text in it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my code

```
<div class="row"> <!-- start faq -->
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

              <?php
              $counter = 1;
            foreach ($faqs as  $faq):
            $subcounter = 2;

           ?>

    <div class="panel-heading heading-bkg" role="tab" id="heading-1">
      <h4>
        <a class="subheading" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-<?php echo $counter;?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-<?php echo $counter;?>">
             <b> <?php echo $faq['subheading'];?> </b> 

        </a>
      </h4>

    </div>


    <div id="collapse-<?php echo $counter;?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $counter;?>">
      <div class="panel-body">

        <?php foreach ($faq['subheadingcontent'] as  $subFaq):?>


            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-<?php echo $counter . '-' .  $subcounter;?>">
              <h1 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-<?php echo $counter;?>" href="#collapse-<?php echo $counter . '-' .  $subcounter;?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-<?php echo $counter . '-' .  $subcounter;?>">
          <?php echo $subFaq['question']; ?>
                </a>
              </h1>
            </div>

            <div id="collapse-<?php echo $counter . '-' .  $subcounter;?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $counter . '-' .  $subcounter;?>">
              <div class="panel-body">
          <?php echo $subFaq['answer']; ?>
              </div>
              </div>
              <?php
      $subcounter++;
     endforeach;?>
        </div>
        </div>



<?php
$counter++;
 endforeach;?>
</div>
</div> <!-- end faq -->
```

I would like to make the header takes as much space as the text within it.

```
<div class="panel-heading heading-bkg" role="tab" id="heading-1">
      <h4>
        <a class="subheading" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-<?php echo $counter;?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-<?php echo $counter;?>">
             <b> <?php echo $faq['subheading'];?> </b> 

        </a>
      </h4>

    </div>
```

currently the panel, or the panel-group, I don't know which, takes the full width of the page.

I don't want to change the width of `panel-group` since the collapsed paragraphs need the full width of the page, I just want the panel-heading size to decrease, be as long as the text, as if someone highlighted the text.

If I want to highlight the text, why not apply background-color to the text? Why would I want to change the panel width?

Because if I highlight the text, and if the sentence does not fit on 1 line, the highlight would be wrong, I want the panel to act as a containter that highlights everything.

Comment: If you add the class `col-6` to the div with class `panel-group`, will it halve the width?

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali Even if that happened, the designer want a highlight as long as the word, as if someone is highlighting the word, not sure if such a solution would satisfy her.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding what you are trying to achieve here. Do you think you can paraphrase the goal?

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali I want `panel-heading` to take as much width as the the text inside it, so if the text is 3 words long, the width of the `panel-heading` should match that, added explanation in my question. So i want `panel-heading` to not have any width so to speak

Comment: Okay got it. I think it might work the way you want to if you add  `display: table;` to the `panel-heading`. Edit: `inline-block` also seems to work!

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali display table, thank you! is what I want, since inline block puts them all on the same row, could you please post an answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as not to mess with the existing css, you can create a new css class with the single property `display: table !important;` and apply that class to the panel-headings you want affected.

```css
.heading-short {
  display: table !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-heading heading-bkg heading-short" role="tab" id="heading-1">
      <h4>
        <a class="subheading" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-<?php echo $counter;?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-<?php echo $counter;?>">
             <b> <?php echo $faq['subheading'];?> </b> 

        </a>
      </h4>

    </div>
```